# Customize webview scrollbar

Tags: android, webview, scrollbar

I have to customize scrollbar in webview - change track and thumb colors, shapes (simple rectangles). I couldn't find any information about customizing webview scrollbar, only listviews.

So far, i created:

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="CustomScrollBar">
    <item name="android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack">true</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarStyle">outsideOverlay</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbars">vertical</item>
    <item name="android:fadeScrollbars">true</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarThumbVertical">@drawable/custom_scrollbar_thumb</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarTrackVertical">@drawable/custom_scrollbar_track</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarSize">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarFadeDuration">2000</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarDefaultDelayBeforeFade">1000</item>
</style>
```

**drawable/custom_scrollbar_track.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <gradient
    android:angle="0"
    android:endColor="@color/gray"
    android:startColor="@color/gray" />
   <corners android:radius="6dp" />
</shape>
```

**drawable/custom_scrollbar_thumb.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<gradient
    android:angle="0"
    android:endColor="@color/green"
    android:startColor="@color/green" />

<corners android:radius="6dp" />

</shape>
```

However, `wv.setScrollBarStyle(R.style.CustomScrollBar);` gives me an error:

> Must be one of: View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY,
>   View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_INSET, View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY,
>   View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_INSET

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was easier than i thought. 
Just added

```
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/custom_scrollbar_thumb"
    android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@drawable/custom_scrollbar_track"
```

attributes to my webview in layout file. Of course i had to remove corners attributes from drawable files.